# keychain config in xamarin forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, keychain, xamarin.auth

I am using xamarin forms
I am trying to use xamarin.Auth to save some informations in the database...and when I did it in android all happend ok ...
But in ios I receive this error...

```
> Xamarin.Auth.AccountStoreException: SaveAsync error = error = Could not save account to KeyChain: -34018
Add Empty Entitlements.plist 
 File /+ New file /+ iOS /+ Entitlements.plist
SecKeyChain.Add returned : -34018
1. Add Keychain Access Groups to the Entitlements file.
2. Turn on the Keychain Sharing switch in the Capabilities section in the app.
```

I am using these lines in my pcl code behind:

```
        account.Properties.Add("teste2", "1");
        account.Properties.Add("teste1", "usereee");
        AccountStore.Create().Save(account, "clastech_montana");
```

[image]

It's all I did... and I searched a lot and I don't know how to turn on the keychain or if it all I did is right..
Please, If you can, help me!

[image]

there is not a place to enable

Answer (score 1):

in your iOS project, open Entitlements.plist, and check "Enable Keychain"

Comment: I am posting a photo of this here..where is it?

Comment: and also you may need to ensure that your entitlements.plist "participates" in the bundle that you are creating.  Go to Project/[YourProjectName] Options/Build/iOs Bundle Signing and set Custom Entitlements to Entitlements.plist